# Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

changepasswordbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{

        //String userconpassword = conpassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();       

        Cursor c = camera.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM member_tbl WHERE email = '"+useremail+"';",null);
        c.moveToFirst();
            if (newpassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase().equals(conpassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase())){
                //try{

                    String usernewpassword = newpassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase(); 

                    String encryptnewuserpassword = EncodeDecodeAES.encrypt(seedWith16Chars, usernewpassword);
                    //Log.e("Encrypt", encryptnewuserpassword);
                    String decryptuserpassword = EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(seedWith16Chars, encryptnewuserpassword);
                    //Log.e("Decrypt", decryptuserpassword);


                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    Log.e("Decrypt", decryptuserpassword+c.getCount());
                    //c.getCount();
                    values.put("memberid", c.getString(0));
                    values.put("fname", c.getString(2));
                    values.put("lname", c.getString(3));
                    values.put("secretanswer", c.getString(5));
                    values.put("secretquestion", c.getString(6));
                    values.put("email", c.getString(4));
                    values.put("password", encryptnewuserpassword);



                    Log.e("Encrypt", encryptnewuserpassword);
                camera.update("member_tbl", values, "email='"+useremail+"'", null);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "password has been changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChangePassword.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();           

            //} catch (Exception e) {

            //         Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());

            //     }    
            }
                else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "new password and confirm password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {

             Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());

         }  
    }
});
```

in this code i get an `03-21 04:08:29.040: E/Exception(2943): Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` im running out of ideas ive search for this kind of error but they are not the same as mine i have `cursor.moveToFirst();` in my code so its not the problem when i searched for this error they say that you probobly miss `cursor.moveToFirst();` thats why you get error but i have that code what seem to be wrong here

Comment: what do you mean the cursor is empty?you mean to say that the cursor didnt find a matching email so it popped this error?

Comment: you made a query to get back that cursor. Is that possible that the query returned no values? Check for c.getCount(). See what values is returning

Comment: +1 you are the man...its 0 wtf how did i get that zero..can you further assist me on this?

Comment: Where do you get **c**? We want to see that code: where you retrieve the cursor.

Comment: @HakHak post the query

Comment: i post the entire code is a button click for change password

Comment: probably there is no value that matches useremail inside member_tbl

Comment: that is what i was thinking when you said to check for c.getCount maybe i should provide the proper useremail thanks for the idea mate +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `c.moveToFirst();` with `if(c.moveToFirst())`

`moveToFirst()` will return true if cursor is not empty.

Comment: should i enclose all the code inside if(c.moveToFirst()){ all code}